# Julia JuMP garbage collection time

Tags: garbage-collection, julia, julia-jump

I'm new to Julia and is trying to use JuMP to solve a NLP, below is the code

```
m = JuMP.Model(solver=Ipopt.IpoptSolver(max_iter=50,tol=1e-6))

function lkhf(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8)
x = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8]
@time ll = loglikelihood(x,pdpoeFacSim,intercept, pdpoeFacMean, pdpoeFacInitial, pdpoeTarget, pdVar, poeVar,corPDPOE,resRnd)
return ll
end

JuMP.register(m, :lkhf, 8, lkhf, autodiff=true)

@nlobjective(m, Min, lkhf(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8))
```

As you can see from the code, I try to time each time the solver calls my objective function and notice something, below is part of the output:

```
0.224411 seconds (47.41 k allocations: 198.016 MiB, 54.80% gc time)
0.027915 seconds (30.61 k allocations: 22.983 MiB, 21.84% gc time) 
0.213348 seconds (47.41 k allocations: 198.016 MiB, 56.25% gc time)    
0.026281 seconds (30.61 k allocations: 22.983 MiB, 22.52% gc time)    
0.214388 seconds (47.41 k allocations: 198.016 MiB, 55.36% gc time)    
0.028030 seconds (30.61 k allocations: 22.983 MiB, 22.65% gc time)
```

I don't quite understand why calling same objective function cause significantly different gc time.

Could you please give me some advise on how I can speed up my code?